# How to get number of classes of an element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having an element such as:

```
<div class="one two three four five six seven eight nine ten"> </div>
```

How can I get number of classes that this element has?

In fact, what I actually need is to know how to get the "seven" class, but I guess I need to count them, since this class is dynamic, so I need to get it by its index or position (I suppose)

¿Any idea how to figure this out?

Comment: Is there some reason you need to do this very trivial task with JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Read the className and split on the whitespace.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("div").className.split(/\s/))
```

```html
<div class="one two three four five six seven eight nine ten"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of classes by using `classList` in plain Javascript or `prop("class")` in jquery

```js
var _el = document.querySelector("div");
console.log(_el.classList);
console.log($("div").prop("class"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one two three four five six seven eight nine ten"> </div>
```